# How to integrate NodeJS web server with Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am pretty much new to Electron and want to understand basic concepts how to make fully functioning desktop app with it.

I've used vue-cli to create new vue project and just added Electron to the project. The app runs as it should. Now, I want to have functionality, i.e. save todos in a database. For that I would need a web server that would receive a request, store data in database and return some sort of response.

From the architectural point, I want to know what's the best thing to do here? Do I just go and create totally separate node-js app that will serve as a server, while Electron app will just send API calls to it, or is it something else?

**EDIT**

I am aware I can store data in a local variable, but I want to be able to keep the data after app closes and so on.

Comment: No, you don't - to this: _For that I would need a web server that would receive a request, store data in database and return some sort of response._

Comment: Well, I could store those in a, let's say vuex store, but data would be lost when the app is closed. How can I persist data (additionally persist data across multiple devices)? @RandyCasburn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your data just has to exist locally and while your application is installed, you could just use persistant store on electron by using [electron-store](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store).

If you plan on sharing to do's or have some sync functionality involved, you have to do the "normal way" by sending requests to an typical api / webserver backend.
I would recommend using an app friendly and easy to use backend framework like [Parse](https://parseplatform.org/) or if looking for a cloud service [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) should fit your needs as the free tier is less data / request intensive apps for the beginning.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. So besides using Firebase/Parse, I can also potentially build my own NodeJS API that would handle database (let's say MongoDB), that could potentially be hosted as an API and be called directly from Electron app?

Comment: Yes, for instance by using [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express) as webserver and [axois](https://github.com/axios/axios) to handle the requests in nodeJS

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to persist data across multiple devices you should build a completely separate web service that the app can call.